# Counting the Number of Occurrences of a Multi-Word Phrase in Text with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, nlp

I have a problem, I need to count the frequency of a word phrase appearing within a text field in a PostgreSQL database.

I'm aware of functions such as `to_tsquery()` and I'm using it to check if a phrase exists within the text using `to_tsquery('simple', 'sample text')`, however, I'm unsure of how to count these occurrences accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the words are contained just once in the string (I am supposing here that your table contains two columns, one with an `id` and another with a text column called `my_text`):

```
SELECT
     count(id)
FROM
     my_table
WHERE
     my_text ~* 'the_words_i_am_looking_for'
```

If the occurrences are more than one per field, this nested query can be used:

```
SELECT
     id,
     count(matches) as matches
FROM (
     SELECT
          id,
          regexp_matches(my_text, 'the_words_i_am_looking_for', 'g') as matches
     FROM
          my_table
) t
GROUP BY 1
```

The syntax of this function and much more about string pattern matching can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html).

Comment: I'm looking to count multiple occurrences within a single text field, this would only count once per column.

For Example: Let's say i'm looking for "sample text" out of "this is a sample text", I'd expect it to count once, but if it checked another entry "sample text is sample text", I'd expect it to count twice. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I have edited my answer after you have added more details.

Comment: That looks like what i'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: Sure, sorry, was going to wait till I fully implement it. But it's doing what I've asked.